# Is there a way to chain methods which return an Option-Type in a way like getOrElse does but keeps the option-type

Tags: scala

Given snippet composes of method calls, which return an option type. I'd like to call the next method if previous call returned None. I'm able to accomplish this with this snippet

```
def amountToPay : Option[TextBoxExtraction] =
  getMaxByFontsize(keywordAmountsWithCurrency) match {
    case None => getMaxByFontsize(keywordAmounts) match {
      case None  =>  highestKeywordAmount match {
        case None => getMaxByFontsize(amountsWithCurrency) match {
          case None => highestAmount
          case some => some
        }
        case some => some
      }
      case some => some
    }
    case some => some
  }
```

but it looks quite messy. So I hope there is abetter way to do it.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but if you want to chain success (use `Some x` as input to the next function) you can use `for`: `for (myWife <- getSpouse(me) ; mySIL <- getSister(myWife); myBIL <- getSpouse(mySIL); myBro <- getBrother(me); if (myBro == myBIL)) yield myBro`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yep, `orElse` is a little cleaner:

```
def amountToPay : Option[TextBoxExtraction] =
  getMaxByFontsize(keywordAmountsWithCurrency)
    .orElse(getMaxByFontsize(keywordAmounts))
    .orElse(highestKeywordAmount)
    .orElse(getMaxByFontsize(amountsWithCurrency))
    .orElse(highestAmount)
```

You could also just put the items in a `Seq` and then use something like `xs.reduceLeft(_ orElse _)` or `xs.flatten.headOption.getOrElse(highestAmount)`.

Comment: @Nicolas, I agree that your version is a little cleaner, but semicolon inference will bite you in the REPL.

Comment: `:paste` will do the trick in the REPL (I wish we could propose an edit in stackoverflow instead of directly submitting changes)

Comment: Oh, there's also the issue that the parenthesization in my version was _wrong_. So yours is much better.